# Generic function inherit keyof value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the follow function signature:

```
duplicationValidatorAsync<T, K extends keyof T>(
    obsArray: Observable<T[]>,
    key: K,
    equalityFn: EqualityFn = null
)
```

When calling this function, I have the specify the key twice:

```
duplicationValidatorAsync<Organization, 'name'>(obs$, 'name', CommonValidators.caseInsensitiveTrimEqualityFn)
```

Is there a way to avoid having to do this?  It would be nice to be able to call this function and for the key parameter to inherit its value from the generic part of the signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `keyof T` directly:

```
duplicationValidatorAsync<T>(
// Removed K here ---------^
    obsArray: Observable<T[]>,
    key: keyof T,
// Use --^^^^^^^
    equalityFn: EqualityFn = null
) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this!  I think just based on generics and examples, I was under the impression that I had to use it where you removed it.